# Mostrar eco php en div

Tags: php, html

Traigo datos desde una consulta a base de datos y los muestro concatenados en un echo:

```
Titulo / Descripcion / Precio /
```

El signo Pesos ($) está agregado para que aparezca antes del número del precio, para que sea visualmente mejor, ya que en la base de datos solo está guardado el valor, quedando así :

```
echo $row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio'];
```

El echo funciona correctamente y muestra lo siguiente:

```
Cinto De Cuero Para Hombre.Cinto De Cuero Exelente Calidad, Diversos Modelos $ 1350.00
```

Ahora el problema es cuando quiero mostrar eso mismo en un `<div>`, para formatearlo con css ya que como es una publicación de venta debe quedar mas atractiva.

El código en el `<div>` es el siguiente:

```
<div class="publicacion"><?= $row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio'];?></div>
```

Ahí lo único que me muestra solito y solo es el signo de `$`:

```
$
```

Es decir, el `echo` muestra todo correctamente pero en el `div`, solo aparece el signo de Pesos ($).

### Actualización

Aquí el código entero extraído de los comentarios:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","bd_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} 
$palabra = $_POST['palabra'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posteos WHERE categoria lIKE '%".$palabra."%' ORDER BY precio ASC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio'];
    echo "<br />";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<div class="descripcion"><?php echo $row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio'];?></div>
```

Comment: No me salió bien la pregunta, me falta el saludo a todos y la captura de pantalla.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. No queda claro cuál es el problema, el código parece hacer exactamente lo que se ve en la imagen, excepto por el `$` de abajo. Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/526562/edit) para agregar más detalles, como qué es exactamente lo que quieres que se muestre.

Comment: Segun entiendo, la primera línea de la captura no tiene que ver con el código que has puesto, que se corresponde con la segunda línea. ¿Es cierto esto que digo?  Si es así entonces deberiamos ver tu código PHP que envuelve a esa salida del div, pues seguramente allí está el problema. Intuyo que eso está en un bucle donde evaluas el resultado de una consulta, y debes verificar que esa consulta es correcta y que además devuelve esas columnas que pretendes enviar. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta puslando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para agregar el contexto pedido.

Comment: En el código tienes puesto un `$`, por lo que este lo está escribiendo exactamente como tu se lo pides

Comment: Hola a todos gracias por responder, si la pregunta cargo mal, así que voy a tratar de aclararlo.

Comment: traigo datos desde una Query y Los Muestro concatenados en un echo: Titulo / Descripcion / Precio /, El Signo Pesos ($) Está Agregado para que aparesca antes del número del precio, para que sea visualmente mejor ya que en la bd solo está guardado el valor. entonces queda así : echo $row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio']; El echo funciona correctamente y muestra lo siguiente : Cinto De Cuero Para Hombre.Cinto De Cuero Exelente Calidad, Diversos Modelos $ 1350.00

Comment: Ahora El Problema Es Cuando Quiero mostrar eso mismo en un div, para formatearlo con css ya que como es una publicación de venta debe quedar mas atrctiva, el código en el div es el siguiente: <div class="publicacion"><?= $row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio'];?></div> ahí lo único que me muestra solito y solo es el signo de $ Se Entiende ?

Comment: He formateado tu pregunta para que se entienda, pero sigo diciendote lo mismo de antes, nos hace falta ver tu contexto que envuelve a la salida con el  `div` pues quizás lo estás haciendo desde otra parte donde $row ya no tiene valores (tiene toda la pinta de ser eso, pero a ciegas poco más podemos decirte)

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posteos WHERE categoria lIKE '%".$palabra."%' ORDER BY precio ASC");
  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo $row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio']; //these are the fields that you have stored in your database table employee
      echo "<br />";
      }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

Comment: <div class="viejo"><?= echo $row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio'];?></div>




<?php //OJO, todo en un bloque PHP  

    printf("<div class=\"publicacion\">%s%s$%s</div>",$row['titulo'],$row['descripcion'],$row['precio']); El div" viejo" es como estaba y el printf tal cual me lo propusieron, ambos muestran lo mismo solo el signo $

Comment: @Mbf1965 ¿no te das cuenta de la diferencia entre ambos códigos que tu mismo has pegado?  En el primero con el **$result** estás creando un bucle con `while` donde defines `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` y luego ese bucle lo cierras antes del mysqi_close(), y dentro haces el **echo** correctamente.   ***En el segundo*** no lo pones dentro de ese bucle y por lo tanto no sabe lo que es **$row** y no muestra sus datos. ¿Lo tienes en archivos distintos todo eso o en el mismo archivo?  Si esta en el mismo archivo lo podras corregir rapido y bien, en caso contrario tienes que darnos + datos

Comment: Hola master no no, todo está dentro del mismo php ahí te paso el codigo completo sin el user y pass de la bd:        <?php

$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","bd_name");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

Comment: $palabra = $_POST['palabra'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posteos WHERE categoria lIKE '%".$palabra."%' ORDER BY precio ASC");
  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo $row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio']; 
      echo "<br />";
      }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

     
    <div class="descripcion"><?php echo $row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio'];?></div>

Comment: @Mbf1965, la zona de comentarios no es adecuada para poner código, por favor edita la pregunta para ponerlo ahí, lo más completo posible: Consulta - Ciclo - Mostrar datos - Cierre de conexión - Fin del script.

Comment: Hola triby, si es que no conozco bien el sistema de posteo y hay cosas que no se como se colocan correctamente, ayer por ejemplo subi una captura de pantalla que nunca apareció y parte de lo que escribi tampoco.

Comment: @Mbf1965 si, cuesta un poco acostumbrarse al editor, pero si no intentas nada raro y usas los botones ya tienes suficiente. Fíjate que tambien el editor tiene una Ayuda que puedes consultar. Y fíjate tambien que cuando estás editando una pregunta, aparte de la zona de edición, ya estás viendo como va quedando un poco más abajo.  Te he dado la respuesta correcta, échale un vistazo, pruébala y ya nos dirás. Básicamente he puesto lo del div dentro del bucle donde defines el $row.

Comment: Master lo tuyo del cierre del while si me sirvió ya que ahí se cerraba el echo y si en el div ya no habían datos, y me sirvió el ´codigo de luis garcía donde incorporaba el div dentro del php, asi que con ambas cosas solucioné, ahora n s cmo marcar ambas respuestas como adecuadas ya que soy nuevo en programacion y mas nuevo en el foro. si me explicas como los valido a los dos. gracias, y abraz.

Comment: @Mbf1965 Acepta la que quieras, pero solo puede ser una (como los immortales!). En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante aceptarlas cuando son válidas para tu pregunta.  Solo un detalle, sin querer entrar en polémica. La solución que has encontrado, que he posteado en una respuesta, y que crees que Luis te ha indicado (sinceramente no veo donde), es lo que te decia hace unas 11 horas en mi primer comentario, y repetí despues en otros más. Dicho esto acepta la que quieras, pero asegúrate que servira a otros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ponlo así, para que quede dentro del bucle donde esta definido **$row**:

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo '<div class="descripcion">'.$row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio'].'</div>';
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Gracias espero haberlo echo bien, acepté la respuesta con el tilde verde, y me alegra mucho que sacrifiquen su tiempo y compartan conocimiento con quienes venimos de abajo. Abrazos Para Todos.

Comment: @Mbf1965 Sí, has aceptado correctamente una respuesta, por eso ahora aparece el "tick" verde al lado de esta respuesta. Me alegra que te haya gustado el sitio, pero debo informarte que tiene unas normas, que no es un foro, y que básicamente se basa en preguntas concretas bien formuladas y respuestas concretas bien explicadas.  En tu caso, al desconocer tu contexto, hemos abusado todos de los comentarios, como si de un foro se tratara, y eso no debe ocurrir. Para la próxima vez te recomiendo estas lecturas: 1) [ask], 2) [tour] y 3) [example] para aprender a colaborar mejor, gracias

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que intentas leer los datos que hay en `$row` fuera de contexto.

Por otra parte, evita la sintaxis abreviada de PHP, así como la mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML. Ambas prácticas producen un código confuso y difícil de analizar/depurar.

Funciones como `printf`, o concatenar contenido, te pueden ayudar a escribir un código más limpio, trabajando siempre dentro de un mismo bloque PHP, abriendo bloques HTML solamente en caso de necesitar escribir mucho contenido HTML sin mezcla de contenido PHP.

Por ejemplo, para este caso, lo puedes resolver más limpiamente con `printf()`:

```
<?php //OJO, todo en un bloque PHP  

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posteos WHERE categoria lIKE '%$palabra%' ORDER BY precio ASC"); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        printf("<div class=\"publicacion\">%s%s$%s</div>",$row['titulo'],$row['descripcion'],$row['precio']);
    } 
    mysqli_close($con);            
?>
```

Simplemente se ponen marcadores (`%s` en este caso) y al final los valores respectivos.

#### Otras recomendaciones

- En PHP, cuando usas comillas dobles, puedes poner variables y comillas simples dentro sin necesidad de concatenar. Si observas, he aplicado esa práctica en la instrucción SQL. Mientras más claro sea tu código, mejor.
- Tu forma de consultar a la base de datos aquí es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Considera usar consultas preparadas para prevenir ese riesgo.
- La API mysqli tiene un método más apropiado para leer los datos de acuerdo al uso que les das, se trata de `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. Digo esto porque `mysqli_fetch_array()` te trae los datos dos veces, indexados en forma numérica y asociativa, y no necesitas ambas formas. Eso no se ve en pantalla, pero esos datos vienen a memoria, ocupando espacio y recursos.

Comment: En la primera versión de su pregunta sí usaba echo.  Creo más bien que lo está poniendo en algún lugar donde $row no tiene datos y no ve los errores.

Comment: Tienes razón @masterguru, además OP usa la versión abreviada de `echo` en su nuevo código: error de apreciación por mi parte.

Comment: Si, creo que por una vez acierto :-)  Elimina la respuesta si quieres, gracias

Comment: Hola, como va. Cedano, con printf muestra lo mismo, solo el signo pesos,

Answer (score 0):

intenta escribirlo asi, ya si no funciona intenta verificar si le esta llegando datos a la variable $row ya que si esta no tiene valor solo te imprimira el caracter $ y 3 yo me voy mas a que la variable $row no tiene datos

```
<div class="publicacion"><?php echo($row['titulo'] . $row['descripcion'] ." $ " . $row['precio']); ?></div>
```

o en su defecto

```
<?php echo("<div class=publicacion> $row[titulo]  $row[descripcion]  $ $row[precio] </div>"); ?>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: Hola Luis como va, no ninguna de las dos opciones que me das resulta, todo muestra solo el signo de pesos, creo que si estan teniendo razon en cuanto a que los valores estan vacios al momento de mostrarlos, pero no entiendo porque, ya que como echo php si son válidos y los muestra correctamente, es mas el codigo tuyo : echo("<div class=publicacion> $row[titulo]  $row[descripcion]  $ $row[precio] </div>"); Lo puse antes de cerrar conexion a bd por las dudas y nada asi que voy a  seguir buscando a ver que onda. gracias igual por la ayuda ya que lo que no sirve,  sirve para descartar opciones.

Comment: Luis Tu dato al final si me sirvió, el tema es que yo estaba usando un wile que incluía el echo que funcionaba correctamente, pero el div estaba después del cierre } por lo que cuando solicitaba el echo dentro del div ya no habia nada,

Comment: así que coloqué tu ´codigo echo("<div class=publicacion> $row[titulo]  $row[descripcion]  $ $row[precio] </div>"); dentro del propio php y corrí el cierre del while al final y ahí si , el div muestra el contenido del eco. ahora no se como marco tu respuesta como acertada ya que la solución era incorporar el div al php y no incorporar el eco en el html, como lo sugeriste apropiadamente.

Comment: Mbf1965 lo que acabas de comentar a Luis es lo que @masterguru te viene diciendo hace raaato: es un problema contextual, no funcionaba porque estabas queriendo usar `$row` **fuera de contexto**. La respuesta que merece ser aceptada es la de master, porque él ha dedicado más tiempo al asunto. En mi respuesta he querido señalarte algunas prácticas que puedes aplicar para blindar/optimizar/clarificar tu código.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias, a veces pienso que me vuelvo invisible cuando escribo demasiadas cosas en los comentarios y se cansan de leerme :-)

Comment: @masterguru no, más bien creo que algunos OP se centran tanto en querer resolver el problema, que no analizan con calma el problema en sí mismo (que no es otra cosa que un código mal escrito o con una lógica errónea), ni las soluciones o consejos que les son sugeridos. Aunque en este caso puede que se haya mezclado la inexperiencia de OP en el sitio (dificultad para escribir/formatear la pregunta) con lo dicho anteriormente. En fin, cuando no encuentras la solución de algo, conviene tomar un respiro y volverlo a analizar desde cero, lógica y sintácticamente.

Comment: No no, Es que a veces se comete el error de dar por descontado que quien pregunta ya tiene cierta capacidad y conocimiento como para entender la respuesta, sin embargo la respuesta debería ser orientada mas bien, a quien todavía conoce poco y no entiende bien, por lo que asimilar y entender la respuesta puede tomarle mas tiempo del que se esperaba, en definitiva, quien pregunta es porque no sabe o no entiende, así que la respuesta debe ser orientada para quien no sabe ni entiende :) Gracias, y abrazos para tod@s ( Esto no es una crítica sino solo una simple opinión).

Comment: @Mbf1965 Entiendo perfectamente lo que dices, pero la próxima vez no te cortes y pregunta que quieren decir los comentarios que no entiendas para así adaptarnos a tu lenguaje en lugar de dar por supuesto que conocias palabras de la jerga del programador como bucle, salida, consulta, columnas, contexto, etc... A mi no me molesta para nada, y en mi caso no me cuesta demasiado ir paso a paso con quien lo necesite, pero debe decirlo, claro, no soy adivino :-)  Saludos!